# Replace only ampersands in string contains htmlentities

Tags: php

Example string: `Lorem ipsum &quot;Sit & Amet&quot;`
 I want to replace ampersand between Sit and Amet, but `str_replace()` have replaced ampersands in `&quot` string. 
In result i need take this `Lorem ipsum &quot;Sit &amp; Amet&quot;`.

Comment: can you reliably do the `str_replace` on `[space]&[space]` so that you only replace & that are inbetween words?

Comment: thanks, but i need universal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = "Lorem ipsum &quot;Sit & Amet&quot;";
$string = htmlentities(html_entity_decode($string), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

This converts the `&quot;`s back to real quotes first, then re-encodes all the entities (quotes and ampersands).

EDIT: added UTF8 encoding

Comment: This work, but htmlentities(html_entity_decode($string)) replaced my cyrillic symbols to "Ð�Ð°Ñ�Ñ�Ð°Ñ�Ñ�" symbols

Answer (score 0):

You can use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) to encode characters to their HTML entities: `&` becomes `&amp;`.

The other way around can be achieved with [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode): `&amp;` becomes `&`.

Your problem is a bit vague so I can't give a practical solution, but with these two functions you should be able to work around html entity issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "&quot; Apples & Oranges &quot;";
$content = preg_replace("/&(?!([\w\n]{2,7}|#[\d]{1,4});)/"," ",$content); 
echo $content;
```

to remove the spaces, change the line to this:

`$content = preg_replace("/&(?!([\w\n]{2,7}|#[\d]{1,4});)/","",$content);`